# getting Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: window.crypto.getRandomValues is not a function error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am able to run the same code on other applications, but unable to run the same code on specific application.
the browser has started successfully, launched the application, the while locating elements i am getting:

```
"org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: window.crypto.getRandomValues is not a function" this error.
```

error in console:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 106.0.5249.61 (511755355844955cd3e264779baf0dd38212a4d0-refs/branch-heads/5249@{#569}) on port 51705
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Oct 25, 2022 5:18:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected upstream dialect: W3C
Oct 25, 2022 5:18:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
INFO: Found exact CDP implementation for version 106
Application launched successfully
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: window.crypto.getRandomValues is not a function
  (Session info: chrome=106.0.5249.119)
Build info: version: '4.5.0', revision: 'fe167b119a'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '16.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [d2f82fd9eda093fbeb1872f16a7eca77, findElement {using=xpath, value=//button[@id='signIn_En']}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 106.0.5249.119, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 106.0.5249.61 (511755355844..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Soumya.B\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:65297}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:65297/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 106.0.5249.119, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: d2f82fd9eda093fbeb1872f16a7eca77
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:547)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation$ElementFinder$2.findElement(ElementLocation.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation.findElement(ElementLocation.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:365)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:357)
    at sample.Sample1.main(Sample1.java:23)
```

Comment: Add your `code` please

Comment: If something overwrites window.crypto maybe?